# discord.js how to transfer args between commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to transfer args; I have tried putting them as a global variable, though I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Command with the args :

```js
let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
const args = messageArray.slice(1);
    
    
const invite = await message.channel.createInvite();
if(cmd === `${prefix}order`) {

    if(!args) return message.reply("Please specify what you would like to order.");

        
    baseOrderNumber++;
    let order = args.join(" ");

    const orderEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    orderIcon = "https://i.imgur.com/Le0Eist.png"
    orderEmbed.setTitle("New Order")
    orderEmbed.setColor("#FF2D00")
    orderEmbed.setThumbnail(orderIcon)
    orderEmbed.addField("Order Number", baseOrderNumber)
    orderEmbed.addField("Order", order)
    orderEmbed.addField("Customer", message.author)
    orderEmbed.addField("Server Invite", invite)

    bot.channels.cache.get('723838675489914891').send(orderEmbed)    
    let eekowo = fs.writeFileSync('orderAuthors.txt', message.author.tag, order); 
}
```

Command that needs the args :

```js
if(cmd === `${prefix}deliver`){
        let eekowo2 = fs.readFileSync('orderAuthors.txt', 'utf8')
        deliverEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        deliverIcon = message.guild.iconURL
        deliverEmbed.addField("Invite", invite)
        deliverEmbed.addField("Customer", eekowo2)
        deliverEmbed.addField("Items", orderEmbed.order)
        message.author.send(deliverEmbed)
}
```

How would I transfer them over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could write them into a **json** file, and require them when needed, *or* simply do something like :

```js
// Your command with the args
if(args) { client.transferedArgs = args; }

// Deliver command
let oldArgs = client.transferedArgs;
```